# httpclient garbling extended characters

Tags: utf-8, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using httpclient to retrieve remote urls and need to grab things such as titles.

In some cases, I get garbled extended characters as in the case of this url

http://olhardigital.uol.com.br/noticia/bilionaria-mais-jovem-da-historia-quer-revolucionar-exames-de-sangue/43586

I've tried playing around with all sorts of settings, to no avail. Any suggestions? My config is as follows:

```
private CloseableHttpClient httpclient = RemotePageUtils.getThreadSafeClient();

public String processMethod(String url, OutputStream out) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException{

    [...]

    BufferedReader in = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    HttpGet httpget = null;

    CloseableHttpResponse resp = null;

    try {

        httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        resp = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        entity = resp.getEntity();

        String inLine;

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(),"UTF-8"));

        while ((inLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            out.write(inLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }

    } finally {

        [...]

    }
    return null;
}

private static CloseableHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {

    SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
            .setTcpNoDelay(true)
            .build();

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(3000)
            .setSocketTimeout(7000)
            .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false)
            .build();

    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept-Charset","ISO-8859-1,US-ASCII,UTF-8,UTF-16;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"));
    //accept gzipped
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,x-gzip,deflate,sdch"));


    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
            .build();

    return client;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blindly interpreting all downloaded pages as UTF-8, but the example link you gave is not in UTF-8, but ISO-8859-1.

An accented letter in ISO-8859-1 is one byte >=128, where in UTF-8 such bytes have to follow specific patterns, in other case they are treated as damaged.

But why are you decoding bytes you have downloaded, just to write bytes to a file?

Instead of:

```
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(),"UTF-8"));
 while ((inLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     out.write(inLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 }
```

and converting bytes to strings and back, you should just copy the bytes.

You can do it with Apache Commons IO:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(), out);
```

or manually, with pure Java:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[16 * 1024];
int len = 0;
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
while ((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

Comment: This code is a little reduced for readability as I'm actually reading the lines to process them. I modified the code to guess the character set and it now works and adapt the Inputstreamreader accordingly. So, I will accept your answer as it pointed me in the right direction, even though it doesn't completely answered the problem